# why \b works only sometimes with javascript str.match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function which attempts to identify the language of a piece of text and see if matches a specific language.

For example, I send the function the language of "Italian" and it attempts to see if the text contains a certain number of very common Italian words.

Part of the code looks like this and it works absolutely fine:

```
switch ( defLanguage ) {
    case "Italian":
        var foreign_count = str.match(/\b(non|di|che|è|e|la|il|un|a|per|in|una|mi|sono|ho|ma|l'|lo|ha|le)\b/g).length;
        break;
    case "German":
        var foreign_count = str.match(/\b(das|ist|Sie|ich|nicht|die|es|und|der|was|ein|zu|er|in|sie|mir|mit|den|auf|mich)\b/g).length;
        break;
}
```

This returns **foreign_count** which tells me how many "foreign" words are in the text.

So far, so good. But with French there's a problem.

If I put the **\b** word boundary around the possible words it doesn't work (i.e. the javascript stops from then on).

```
var foreign_count = str.match(/\b(le|de|un|à|avec|et|en|je|que|pour|dans|ce|il|qui|ne|sur|se|pas|plus|par)\b/g).length;
```

However, if I remove the **\b** then it does work!

```
var foreign_count = str.match(/(le|de|un|à|avec|et|en|je|que|pour|dans|ce|il|qui|ne|sur|se|pas|plus|par)/g).length;
```

This is driving me up the wall. The **\b** works fine with the German & Italian (and other language) examples, but doesn't work with French. I can't for the life of me work out why and obviously I need the word boundaries in there so I need to sort this out.

Any help would be *much* appreciated!

====== further information ========

The problem, it seems, is not related to non-ascii characters.

This does not work:

str.match(/\b(jag|det|du|inte|att|en|och|har|vi|i|han|vad|som)\b/g).length;

But this does:

str.match(/\b(jag|det|du|inte|att|en|och|har|vi|i|han|vad|om)\b/g).length;

It seems that certain words (all in ascii chars) cause an error along with the \b marker. I can't use (?<=\s|^) as lookbehind is not supported in Javascript by all accounts.

Comment: On a further tack, Greek doesn't work either with or without the \b

Comment: What likely happens is your regex fails when encountering non-ASCII characters. See [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters), maybe it'll help.

Comment: Oh, and also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/7470253)

Comment: This is getting weird. If the regex is **str.match(/\b(in)\b/g).length** then it DOES work but if it's **str.match(/\b(dans)\b/g).length** then it doesn't! Is there something wrong with the **dans** characters? I tried on longer lists of words and it always falls down on these.

Comment: Use whitespace boundary's instead `(?<!\S)(?:a|b|c)(?!\S)`, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how `\b` is [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> Matches a word boundary. This is the position where a **word character**
>   is not followed or preceeded by another **word-character**, such as
>   between a letter and a space. Note that a matched word boundary is not
>   included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word
>   boundary is zero.

... and how *word character* (aka `\w`) is defined:

> Matches any alphanumeric character from the **basic Latin alphabet,
>   including the underscore**. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

Clearly `à` is not a word character so it cannot help match a word boundary.