# Removing text containing non-english character

Tags: r, text

This is my sample dataset:

```
Name <- c("apple firm","苹果 firm","Ãpple firm")
Rank <- c(1,2,3)
data <- data.frame(Name,Rank)
```

I would like to delete the Name containing non-English character. For this sample, only "apple firm" should stay.

I tried to use the `tm` package, but it can only help me delete the non-english characters instead of the whole queries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would check out this related Stack Overflow post for doing the same thing in javascript. [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

To translate this into R, you could do (to match non-ASCII):

```
res <- data[which(!grepl("[^\x01-\x7F]+", data$Name)),]

res
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#        Name  Rank
#       <chr> <dbl>
#1 apple firm     1
```

And to match non-unicode per that same SO post:

```
  res <- data[which(!grepl("[^\u0001-\u007F]+", data$Name)),]

  res
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#        Name  Rank
#       <chr> <dbl>
#1 apple firm     1
```

Note - we had to take out the `NUL` character for this to work. So instead of starting at `\u0000` or `x00` we start at `\u0001` and `\x01`.

Answer (score 10):

`stringi` package has the convenience function `stri_enc_isascii`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_enc_isascii(data$Name)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

As the name suggests,

> the function checks whether all bytes in a string are in the [[ASCII] set 1,2,...,127](http://www.asciitable.com/) (from `?stri_enc_isascii`).

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to regex would be to use `iconv` and than filter for non NA entries:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
         mutate(Name = iconv(Name, from = "latin1", to = "ASCII")) %>%
         filter(!is.na(Name))
```

What happens in the mutate statement is that the strings are converted from latin1 to ASCII. [Here's a list](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html) of the characters covered by latin1 aka ISO 8859-1. When a string contains a character that is not on the latin1 list, it cannot be converted to ASCII and becomes NA.

Comment: I have the same issue as @Frank, when I run `from = "ASCII"` and `to = "latin1"` it manages to convert the characters (although inaccurately) and doesn't give me the `NA`s.

Comment: @Frank, true dat, mixed up things. I edited my answer accordingly