# How to remove Arabic text from string

Tags: r, string, text, arabic, text-classification

I have copied some data describing cholera cases in regions of Yemen from an online database into a text file. The names of each region are given in both English and Arabic in a single string. I would like to remove the Arabic in R, and be left with just the English names.

This is what the English/Arabic string looks like when read into R:

`regions <- c("Al Hudaydah Ø§Ù„Ø­Ø¯ÙŠØ¯Ø©", "Hajjah Ø­Ø¬Ø©")`

I would like to be left with just the English
`"Al Hudaydah" "Hajjah"`

I have tried using
`str_replace_all(regions, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")` and `replace_non_ascii(regions)` but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/arabicStemR/man/removePrefixes.html did u try that

Comment: this post might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049015/removing-text-containing-non-english-character

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach may be to simply use `gsub`

```r
gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "", regions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I have found the solution to my problem. The issue was in the reading in of the text file. If it contains Arabic (or presumably any non-latin scripts), you need to use `encoding = 'UTF-8'`

e.g.

`txt <- readLines("Arabic_English_script.txt")` returns

> "Al Hudaydah Ø§Ù„Ø­Ø¯ÙŠØ¯Ø©" "Taizz ØªØ¹Ø²"

whereas `txt <- readLines("Arabic_English_script.txt", encoding = 'UTF-8')` returns

> "Al Hudaydah الحديدة" "Taizz تعز"

Once the text has been properly imported, then `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", txt)` returns

> "AlHudaydah" "Taizz"

(Note, it still removes the spaces. Not sure how to fix that one.)

Comment: I *think* `"[^[:alnum:] ]"` will work (add a space after the right bracket: this would be "remove all characters that are not alphanumeric **or space**" )  Note this is similar to @Hugh's answer (slightly better because of the remote chance of using a locale where there are letters outside the range `A-Z`, e.g. Estonian)