# How can I use Regular Expression to match Chinese characters like ，。‘；’

Tags: javascript, regex, regula

I'm using javascript to convert string to what I want!!
Can I use Regular Expression and use what  Regular Expression??
Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Chinese characters are basically Unicode cahracters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get corresponding Unicode code for these Chinese characters. Here is a helpful [tool](http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html).

```
character code(base 10) code(hex)
， 65307 0xff1b
。 65292 0xff0c
； 12290 0x3002
```

Second, use these Unicode code to form regexp.

js:

```
/[\u3002\uff0c\uff1b]/.test('A string contains Chinese character。')
true
```