# Regex matching letters – including non-latin, but excluding emoji

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

I have a need for a javascript regex that would match words in any language, but fail for emoji or any other character. Solution here: [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) matches all letters plus pictograms and emoji (`[^\u0000-\u007F]+`).

Modifying it a bit seems to accomplish what I need, but I'm not sure how safe it is: `([a-zA-Z]|[^\u0000-\u007F\u200d-\u3299\ud83c-\udfff\ufe0e\ufe0f])+`

Example:
`America`
`Österreich`
`Россия`
`Ελλάδα`

Should only match letters and stop before emoji. Should not match emojis with letter representations, for example: `1️⃣#️⃣*️⃣`

Relevant: http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-variation-sequences.txt

**Bit of context:**
I'm trying to patch this parser: https://github.com/Khan/simple-markdown/blob/master/simple-markdown.js#L1304 to break on emojis, because currently it matches as much text as it can. Without that matching/replacing emoji via that parser is problematic. Removing `\u00c0-\uffff` from the highlighted regex accomplishes what I need, but parser starts breaking up words. Some languages (cyrrillic) get broken per letter, which is not good for performance. I need to either patch that regex to allow letters, but not emojis, or put a regex that catches all text before it.

*Edit: Added some examples*

*Edit: Added language restriction*

Comment: Yep added some examlples

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes#word

Essentially `/[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]/u` given Unicode property escapes support.

Until `\p` is natively supported in JavaScript, you can [transpile this regex](https://mothereff.in/regexpu#input=const+regex+%3D+%2F%28%5B%5Cp%7BAlphabetic%7D%5Cp%7BMark%7D%5Cp%7BDecimal_Number%7D%5Cp%7BConnector_Punctuation%7D%5Cp%7BJoin_Control%7D%5D%2B%29%2Fgu%3B%0Aconst+text+%3D+%60%0AAmharic%3A+%E1%8B%A8%E1%8A%94+%E1%88%9B%E1%8A%95%E1%8B%A3%E1%89%A0%E1%89%A2%E1%8B%AB+%E1%88%98%E1%8A%AA%E1%8A%93+%E1%89%A0%E1%8B%93%E1%88%A3%E1%8B%8E%E1%89%BD+%E1%89%B0%E1%88%9E%E1%88%8D%E1%89%B7%E1%88%8D%0ABengali%3A+%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0+%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AB%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F+%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%81%E0%A6%9A%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%9B-%E0%A6%8F+%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE+%E0%A6%B9%E0%A7%9F%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%9B%E0%A7%87%0AGeorgian%3A+%E1%83%A9%E1%83%94%E1%83%9B%E1%83%98+%E1%83%AE%E1%83%9D%E1%83%9B%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%93%E1%83%98+%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%B0%E1%83%90%E1%83%94%E1%83%A0%E1%83%9D+%E1%83%91%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98%E1%83%A8%E1%83%96%E1%83%94+%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%95%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%90+%E1%83%92%E1%83%95%E1%83%94%E1%83%9A%E1%83%97%E1%83%94%E1%83%95%E1%83%96%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98%E1%83%97%0AMacedonian%3A+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BE+%D1%98%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%0AVietnamese%3A+T%C3%A0u+c%C3%A1nh+ng%E1%BA%A7m+c%E1%BB%A7a+t%C3%B4i+%C4%91%E1%BA%A7y+l%C6%B0%C6%A1n%0A%60%3B%0A%0Alet+match%3B%0Awhile+%28match+%3D+regex.exec%28text%29%29+%7B%0A%09const+word+%3D+match%5B1%5D%3B%0A%09console.log%28%60Matched+word+with+length+%24%7B+word.length+%7D%3A+%24%7B+word+%7D%60%29%3B%0A%7D&unicodePropertyEscape=1).

Answer (score 0):

`\pL` matches a Unicode letter.

You might want to combine that Unicode category with `\p{Pc}` (connector punctuation) to also catch word combinations like `it's` or `doesn't` by using a character class: `[\pL\p{Pc}]`

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add in the text that I need it in javascript. Your solution would be fine, but not for JS :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, I somehow thought I had read Java...in that case, grab Steve Levithan's XRegExp library (with Unicode plugins)](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript before ES2018 (which got added natively to [many browsers in mid-2020](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes)), the answer is "roll your own"

Here is what I made, after consulting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) and using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression/50828436#50828436) for cleaning up the endless list of unicode codes:

```
const westernEurope = '\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF';
// (u00D7 and u00F7 are math symbols)
const cyrillic = '\u0400-\u04FF';
const japan = '\u30A0-\u30FF';
const chinese = '\u4E00-\u9FA5';

const re = new RegExp(`^[a-zA-Z${westernEurope + cyrillic + japan + chinese}]*$`, 'g');
```

You should also consult Wikipedia if you need other languages or want to double check this (for instance, I only included basic Cyrillic in the cyrillic codes above)

If you can use the latest JavaScript in your project, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters/48902765#48902765) explains how Unicode Property Escapes are just what we need