# arabic and english characters form validation in ionic2

Tags: validation, ionic2, angular2-forms, custom-validators, angular2-formbuilder

I have developed a registration form to allow users to signup for a new account.

in the registration form in Ionic2 and I have to validate some values in the form before submit, one of the values (Full Name) may include either English or Arabic Characters

I used form validation concept as following:

```
this.personalInfoForm = formBuilder.group({
  txtFullName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
  txtNickname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
  SGender: ['', Validators.required],
  txtCommercialName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')])],
  txtDateOfBirth: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

my problem is that the validator only accept English characters and when user enter Arabic characters the validator doesn't recognize it as a valid value so it doesn't accept it

Are there any pattern to make the validator accept Arabic characters, English characters, space

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/4826457

Comment: @suraj thank you very much...Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it...I found that i have to include  \u0600-\u06FF in the pattern...that is what it is written in the link you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently validating only english characters: `Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')`.

You need to find the unicode characters required for the non english language you are validating for.Check [Jeremy Ruten's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters/150078#150078) answer. The arabic character set as mentioned [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) will be `\u0600-\u06FF`.

So your pattern for English and Arabic would be

`Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06FF ]*')`