# using regex in javascript to check if foreign characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to create a simple function that checks if there are foreign characters in my string. Essentially, this is what I'm trying to get:

```
var str_1 = "отправка.py" // should return true
var str_2 = "bla.py" // should return false
var str_3 = "bla23.py" // should return false
var str_4 = "bla23_.py" // should return false
```

I want to make sure that there aren't any foreign characters, while still making sure that I allow everything else (characters like "_", "-", ...).

I'm just trying to avoid the Russian, Mandarin, etc.. alphabets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking only for ASCII. So something like:

```
!/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test('отправка.py');  // => true
!/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test('bla.py');  // => false
```

Comment: this works as expected. thanks a lot!

Comment: Naïvely. If you want to accept Western European or more broadly Latin script, there's å łõť which is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/aw6dfG/1)

```
[^ -~]
```

Alternatively: `[^\x00-\x7F]` (which seems to have already been [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098450/3600709) by [@BlakeSimpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891971/blake-simpson))

#### Usage

```js
const r = /[^ -~]/
const a = [
  "отправка.py",
  "bla.py",
  "bla23.py",
  "bla23_.py"
]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  if(r.exec(s) !== null) {
    console.log(s)
  }
})
```

---

### Explanation

`[^ -~]` Matches everything that's **not** from the space character  (DEC 32) to the tilde `~` symbol (DEC 126) - which are all the visible ASCII characters.

Also, note that I don't use the `g` modifier. This is intentional as the OP is only asking to check whether or not there are foreign characters in the string. That means that so long as 1 character exists in the string that meet those requirements it should be matched (no need to match more than one).

[image: ASCII Table]