# Which ES2018 features are implemented in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Could somebody please help me with the following question:

Where can I find the list of ECMAScript features that have been implemented by Typescript? I'm particularly interested in [RegExp Unicode property escapes](http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_regexp-unicode-property-escapes.html) which was added in ES2018 (which happened pretty recently according to [this post](http://2ality.com/2017/02/ecmascript-2018.html)). I would like to use this feature to add multi-language support for [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22600#issuecomment-371533702), but couldn't find any evidence that it was adopted by Typescript.

P.s. I spent some time and found the following resources [Issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20342), [PR on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20385), [Typescript Roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap), [ES compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Unicode_Property_Escapes).

From my understanding, they are very closely related to my question, but none of them can actually confirm that Unicode property escapes was implemented. I can still fallback to the [transpiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902765/2009145) solution, but it would be nice to use `/\p{L}/u` instead of very long string.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which ES2018 features are implemented in Typescript?

TypeScript only implements stage 3 and above features. Doubt many 2018 features are stage 3 yet. You can find the complete support [list here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

> I'm particularly interested in RegExp Unicode property escapes which was added in ES2018

TypeScript parses this regex just fine :

```
const test = /^\p{White_Space}+$/u.test('\t \n\r');
```

However it doesn't down emit anything to support it for old JS runtimes. In short, it will not work if your runtime doesn't support it.