# Javascript - Add validation pattern to allow at least one non-space char

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to create input and add validation pattern to not allow spaces in input
I found some solutions like this :

```
Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*[a-zA-z0-9 ]")
```

But problem with this pattern is that special charachters (č,ć,ž,đ,š...) are not included

So I need solution without blank (space) input but with special charachters

**EDIT**

For Example if someone insert only one or more spaces I must notice him..
But if he continue inserting some other charachters it's ok.

Example :

```
"   " - not valid

"   Ante Ereš" - valid
```

Comment: It's unclear, your pattern is actually allowing spaces in many places. Could you give some example inputs that should match and some that should not match ?

Comment: also strongly related : [regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters/873600#873600)

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: wait...so you want to invalidate single spaces but allow multiple spaces or the other way around?

Comment: the sentence *only one **or more spaces** (??) I must notice him.. But if he continue inserting some other charachters it's ok.* contradicts itself.

Comment: If pattern matches with only space characters it's invalid. And if there are some other characters beside spaces, pattern is valid. Then space entry is allowed also

Comment: It seems you just want to require at least one non-space char, use `Validators.pattern("\\s*\\S.*")` or `Validators.pattern(/^\s*\S.*$/)`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you Wiktor. I don't understand this regex so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Validators.pattern("\\s*\\S.*")
```

to match a string that contains at least one non-whitespace character. Note that `^`  and `$` anchors are added automatically by Angular and the resulting pattern looks like `/^\s*\S.*$/`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\S` - a non-whitespace
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.