# Firefox throws 'invalid identity escape in regular expression' when using Perl tokens with 'u' flag

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

`/\p{Z}/u.test(' ')` works on Chrome 71.0.3578.98 and returns true, but on Firefox 65.0 it throws the error:
`SyntaxError: invalid identity escape in regular expression`

Is this a problem with ES implementation in Firefox, or I am using the regex wrong, and Chrome is just being nice and interprets that in the desired way?

Comment: FF does not support the features introduced in ECMAScript 2018 standard yet. BTW, why not just use `\s`? `/\s/.test(' ')` should work anywhere.

Comment: Ahh, I see.. I just gave a very simple example with \p{}. In reality I was using something more complicated for sets of different characters, but since the problem was caused by FF failing to interpret \p{}, this example seemed sufficient.
Your comment really suffices for the answer to my question, if you care to post it as such. I didn't realise FF was that slow in implementing it.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Sure, it's related. However, that question and answer do not even mention Firefox. The question here though is much more specific and anyone could encounter this problem when they start trying to use \p regexes in Firefox and it doesn't work. They might benefit from a plain, simple and quick answer that there is just no support for these regexes in Firefox (as of version 65.0).
This question isn't about how to create a regex, but rather about browser compatibility.

Comment: Your answer is there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902765/3832970.