# Ruby - split on nonalphanumeric characters excluding international characters?

Tags: regex, ruby

This is my regex so far which will split on non-alphanumeric characters, including international characters (ie Korean, Japanese, Chinese characters).

```
title = '[MV] SUNMI(선미) _ 누아르(Noir)'
title.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ']/)
```

this is the regex to match any international character:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

Which I got from: [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)  Let'a ssume this is 100% correct (no debating!)

How do I combine these 2 so I can split on non-alphanumeric characters, excluding international characters? The easy part is done. I just need to combine these regex's somehow.

My expected output would be something like this

```
["MV", "SUNMI", "선미", "누아르", "Noir"]
```

TLDR: I want to split on non-alphanumeric characters only (english letters, foreign characters should ***not*** be split on)

Comment: What's your expected result after splitting?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi updated quest

Answer (score 1):

`(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<![^\x00-\x7F]))+`

https://regex101.com/r/EDyluc/1

What is not matched (remains from split) is what you want to keep.

Explained:

```
 (?:
      [^a-zA-Z0-9]                  # Not Ascii AlphaNum
      (?<! [^\x00-\x7F] )           # Behind, not not Ascii range (Ascii boundary)
 )+
```

Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to split on all ascii but non-alphabet characters. You can use this regex which selects all characters within ascii range.

```
[ -@[-`{-~]+
```

This regex having ranges space to `@` then ignoring all uppercase letters then picks all characters from `[` to backtick then ignores all lowercase letters then picks all characters from `{` to `~` as can be seen in ascii table.

In case you want to exclude till extended ascii characters, you can change `~` in regex with `ÿ` and use `[ -@[-`{-ÿ]+` regex.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL3jJ3/1/)**

Check out these Ruby codes,

```
s = '[MV] SUNMI(선미) _ 누아르(Noir)'
puts s.split(/[ -@\[-`{-~]+/)
```

Prints,

```
MV
SUNMI
선미
누아르
Noir
```

**[Online Ruby Demo](https://rextester.com/QYQOQ4520)**

Comment: This isn't precisely what I wanted, but I tried this: title.split(/[^\x00-\x7F]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/) which gives me ["[MV] SUNMI(", "", ") _ ", "", "", "(Noir)"] . I want it to split on non-alphanumeric characters only (english letters, foreign characters should not be split on)

Comment: @HenleyChiu: Did this work for you? Let me know if you have any trouble using it.