# Regular expression to match only letters, space and non-English characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check text with regular expression and i need to check if it contains only letters, spaces and also non english characters.

I have this one:

```
var check = /^[a-zA-Z_0-9][a-zA-Z_0-9\s]*$/g.test(input.value);
```

It works fine but if input.value contains "ã" or "é" it gives false.

I googled and find that you can use unicode filter like this:

```
/\p{L}/u
```

I tryed to combine but with no results.

How can i solve this?

Thank you all.

Comment: `\p{L}` and similar constructs are only supported in new environments, you might just add those characters you want to permit to the character sets for better compatibility

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for your answer. I would like to try your tip but i'm not good with regex. How do i add the characters? Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean something like `^\p{L}[\p{L}\s]*$`?

Comment: What do you define as "*non english characters*"? Does it include Cyrillic? Chinese? Korean? Mathematical notations? Arabic?

Comment: @Sweeper thank you but is not working :/

Comment: @VLAZ for now it would be just portuguese, but yes it would be nice to accept letters from other lang but just letters and numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will include extended latin characters:

```
var check = /^[a-zA-Z_0-9\u00C0-\u017F][a-zA-Z_0-9\u00C0-\u017F\s]*$/g.test(input.value);
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode for more information.