# How to remove or replace unicode characters in text with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have text like this :

```html
<div id="content">
    Com mitius gementibus vivamus ultrices acervis te; Ultimo massapellentesque conspiratione diaminteger antiochiae; Stirpis suadendo, perpensum malesuada nal
    ↚
    fusce Se actibus curae. Mus consectetur paulatim mors ca or purusvestibulum litora,
    ↚
    Repentina venenatis! Conpluribus enimsed Mitius saevientis legum infudere ubi:
    ↚
    Sur quoque commodo tin cum Clematius ra, animis! Varietas dira ad quis nebulas invitis facti tempestates the: Paulatim agebantur Malesuadanullam vero lectus dictumst domus.
</div>
```

how can I remove all `↚`  symbols from text with Javascript

Comment: `'your-content'.replaceAll('your-character', '')` I'm guessing this would work?

Comment: You can use the .replace(regx,' ') -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters

Comment: We need an actual runnable example of something that doesn't work to address your problem.  There isn't anything immediately clear in your example text of something that doesn't work with a simple replace.

Comment: `content.innerText=content.innerText.replace(/↚ /g,"")`

Comment: @HalilÇakar `replaceAll` is available on Chrome (I don't care about other "browsers") from 85.  Mine is at 83.  I'm sure you knew that.  It would have been nice to mention that...

Comment: Yea if needed then regex is the best solution i'm guessing :)

Comment: Personally, I prefer regex - because with `replace(/text/g, "")` you can't use variables or functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var elementText = document.getElementById("content");
elementText.innerHTML = elementText.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("↚", "g"), "");
```

This will replace all of the `↚` with an empty string (essentially removing them).

I'm not quite sure where those strange characters came from though - the slash isn't even a default keyboard slash. Any clue why it could have occurred?