# Regex function not filtering out unicode characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode

I have a string that contains unicode characters that are not needed at all and my Regex is not removing them as expected.

I have tried the code below with the results and expected results shown.

```
string buffer = "÷0130100422758673\u0001Y\u001ean//n\u0004";
buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, @"\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}", String.Empty);

Expected Output: "÷0130100422758673Yan//n";
Actual Output (did not change from input): "÷0130100422758673\u0001Y\u001ean//n\u0004";
```

Edit:

I am closer after finding this [page](http://www.csharphelper.com/howtos/howto_remove_non_ascii.html)

I now get closer to the expected output with the following code, however it removes the leading ÷ symbol that needs to stay:

```
string buffer = "÷0130100422758673\u0001Y\u001ean//n\u0004";
buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, @"[^ -~]+", String.Empty);

Output: "0130100422758673Yan//n";
Desired Output: "÷0130100422758673Yan//n";
```

Comment: There are no entities in the string that your regex matches. See [what your **text** looks like](https://ideone.com/TQzJwL).

Comment: `"\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"` will not match unicode characters. It will match character sequences. To match unicode characters, you would need to use something like `"\u0000-\u007F"`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters#150078). That's just an example, you'll need to define the regex yourself based on your needs.

Comment: You appear to want to remove everything but "non-control code ascii characters", the division symbol `÷` is not an ascii character, so you can't include it while following your requirements. Ascii codes are 0-127, the control codes are 0-31, so 32-127 is what your edit filters to. The division symbol is code 247. You could change your requirements to "non-control code ascii characters and also the division symbol".

Comment: For these kinds of problems it is often very helpful to stop and first determine 1: why does your string contains those characters? 2: why do you not need them? "I don't understand them" is not a good reason for deleting things. 3: why are you using a regular expression to parse it? I remember someone trying to do something similar, and it turned out their "string" was actually binary data, not text, and the "unicode" was actually data they needed to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
string buffer = "÷0130100422758673\u0001Y\u001ean//n\u0004";
buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, @"^(÷)|[^ -~]", "$1");
```

*Details*:

- `^(÷)` - matches and captures the `÷` symbol that is at the start of the string (`^`) into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `[^ -~]+` - just matches any char other than a char in between a space and tilde character range.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jRUoNe/1)